How do I enable Nvidia proprietary drivers on Wayland on Ubuntu 24.04?
I am on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, on my two laptops (Asus K501UW & HP Pavilion Gaming 16 a0004). Both with nvidia graphics card (960m & RTX 2060 max q), both with the proprietary drivers installed (535), and both usually under wayland.
The thing is, the nvidia drivers work only on x11, and I want to stay on Wayland; I make good use of the touchpad gestures.
So, how do I enable the nvidia cards on Wayland? and more importantly, should I? It is not like I am going to use them for gaming, most of the times it is just office stuff and web browsing. But still, how stable or reliable is it?
Thanks.

Does this answer your question? Should you use Wayland over XOrg on an Nvidia card? (Ubuntu 22.04)

@mikewhatever partially. I mean, I get your point, but since Ubuntu 24.04 is a new release I wonder if the improvements are good enough to "experiment" on Wayland, given the fact that I do not intend to game.
